# Call angular2 method from javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-scope, kendo-grid

I am using jquery kendo ui grid and from that edit button i am trying to call angular2 method. My setup is simple:

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor( @Inject(UserService) public userService: UserService,  @Inject(FormBuilder) public fb: FormBuilder) {
...
}


 edit():void{ }

 onInit() {
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
   ....
   click: function () {
     // Call angular2 method of the current instance
   });
}
}
```

It's working code the only issue is this. I can call the angular2 method by just stating

```
 click:this.edit
```

or

```
 click: function () {
         UserComponent.prototype.edit()
       });
```

but in both case the method is not from the current instance. So in this case i cannot make use of the http service or any local variable or methods inside edit

Comment: all Angular methods *are* JavaScript, so your question title doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Yes all angular methods are javascrupt but my title "angular2 **method** " by this i mean the method of an instance. because if you just call this.edit it wont execute the method from the current instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this

```
click: function () {
   this.edit();
}).bind(this);
```

or

```
var self = this;
$("#grid").kendoGrid({

   click: function () {
     self.edit();
   });
```